# generate Fiscal_day_date based on calendar date in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

we have a date dimension table where all the calendar and fiscal dates for 30 years are populated. Now we need to add new column as Fiscal_day_date and our Fiscal year starts from Sep-01. we need output as mentioned below :

[image]

Comment: hope this is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468490/gcp-bigquery-calendar-table-fiscal-year-and-month

Comment: Fiscal month and year generation we have. but the issue is with generating fiscal date for each calendar date:

calender_date Fiscal_day_date
9/1/2022 1/1/2023
9/2/2022 1/2/2023
9/3/2022 1/3/2023
9/4/2022 1/4/2023
9/5/2022 1/5/2023
9/6/2022 1/6/2023
9/7/2022 1/7/2023
9/8/2022 1/8/2023
9/9/2022 1/9/2023
9/10/2022 1/10/2023
9/11/2022 1/11/2023
9/12/2022 1/12/2023
9/13/2022 1/13/2023
9/14/2022 1/14/2023
9/15/2022 1/15/2023